# Implemented Serializable interface but class object is still not serializable

Tags: java, android

The compiler is telling me this class `Position` in not serializable. I'm not sure why as I've implemented the serializble interface

```
private class Position 
    extends CommandParent implements CommandInterface, Serializable {

    public Position(){
        xVal = 10000;
        yVal = 10000;
        zVal = 10000;
        iVal = null;
        jVal = null;
    }

    @Override
    public CommandType getCommandType(){return CommandType.POSITION;}
    @Override
    public String getKey(){return KEY_POSITION;}

}
```

Here is the interface

```
public interface CommandInterface {

    CommandType getCommandType();
    String getKey();
}
```

and the super class

```
public class CommandParent implements Serializable {

// Data
protected Number xVal;
protected Number yVal;
protected Number zVal;
protected Number iVal;
protected Number jVal;

// Getters
protected Number getXcomponent(){ return xVal;}
protected Number getYcomponent(){ return yVal;}
protected Number getZcomponent(){ return zVal;}
protected Number getIcomponent(){ return iVal;}
protected Number getJcomponent(){ return jVal;}

// Setters
public void setXcomponent(Number x) { xVal = x; }
public void setYcomponent(Number y) { yVal = y; }
public void setZcomponent(Number z) { zVal = z; }
public void setIcomponent(Number i) { iVal = i; }
public void setJcomponent(Number j) { jVal = j; }

boolean xEnable = true;
boolean yEnable = true;
boolean zEnable = true;
```

}

Here is my serialization algorithm; I'm passing the class `Position` to the `save` method as an interface type.

```
private void save(CommandInterface command) {

    Log.v(TAG,"save");
    Log.v(TAG,"saving : "+command.getKey());

    try {

        // Create a new file with an ObjectOutputStream.
        File file = new File(mCtx.getFilesDir(), command.getKey());

        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

        // Write something in the file.
        outputStream.writeObject(command); // <=== Throws the error

        // Close and flush the stream.
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Exception: ", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Exception: ", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
```

The error results on this line

```
// Write something in the file.
outputStream.writeObject(command); // <=== Throws the error
```

Here is the stack trace

```
Java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.michael.gloevo1.ActivityGloEvoPage.GloEvoPageActivity
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
     at com.example.michael.gloevo1.ActivityGloEvoPage.CommandManager.save(CommandManager.java:252)
     at com.example.michael.gloevo1.ActivityGloEvoPage.CommandManager.saveCurrentCommand(CommandManager.java:66)
     at com.example.michael.gloevo1.ActivityGloEvoPage.GloEvoPageActivity.onPause(GloEvoPageActivity.java:123)
     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6386)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1311)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3385)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3358)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3333)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap13(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: No it isn't. Tell us *exactly* what the compiler is telling you, and on what line of code.

Comment: No, it's not serializable. How can you tell? I've added the exact line, and the stack trace.

Comment: No the compiler isn't saying that `Position` isn't `Serializable`. I can tell because I know what the compiler does and doesn't say. That is not a compiler error, it is a runtime exception, and it doesn't say 'the class `Position` is not `Serializable`', it says something quite different. Read it.

Comment: Did you implement `CommandInterface` on an Activity?

Comment: @EJP I'm certain I'm passing an instance of `Position` to be serialized. What is the stack trace telling me that I'm not getting?

Comment: @cricket_007 Why do you ask? No I have not. I'm not trying to serialize an activity. Is that what the stack trace is saying?

Comment: That you're not *reading*. It says, quite clearly, `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.michael.gloevo1.ActivityGloEvoPage.GloEvoPageActivity`.

Comment: Did you reference `GloEvoPageActivity.this` inside of a Serializable object, or otherwise hold that as a Context, for example?

Comment: Or is `Position` an inner class? of `GloEvoPageAct‌​ivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The compiler is telling me this class `Position` in not serializable.

No it isn't. The *JVM* is telling you, at runtime, via an exception:

```
Java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.michael.gloevo1.ActivityGloEvoPage.GloEvoPageActivity
```

This is because `Position` is an inner class, for example of `GloEvoPageActivity`, which would mean that a `Position` instance holds a reference to the enclosing `GloEvoPageActivity` instance, which isn't serializable.

Make `Position` a static or top-level class, and resolve any compilation errors that arise.

Comment: Thanks, but `Position` is an inner class of `CommandManager` which is not an activity class. `GloEvoPageActivity` calls the `save` method on a `CommandManager` object.

Comment: It can't be an inner class of anything that isn't itself serializable. Somehow there is a reference from `Position` to `GloEvoPageActivity`, which you need to seek and destroy.

Comment: My solution was to nullify the global context variable passed in from GloEvoPageActivity before writing the object. I have no idea why that works, but it does and thanks for the hints. You can see the code I posted as an answer if it piques your curiosity.

Comment: Making it static is much the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to nullify the global context variable passed in from `GloEvoPageActivity` before writing the object

```
private void save(CommandInterface command) {

    Log.v(TAG,"save");
    Log.v(TAG,"saving : "+command.getKey());
    Log.v(TAG,"command is an instance of position : "+String.valueOf(command instanceof Position));
    Log.v(TAG,"command is an instance of position : "+String.valueOf(command instanceof GloEvoPageActivity));

    try {

        // Create a new file with an ObjectOutputStream.
        File file = new File(mCtx.getFilesDir(), command.getKey());

        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

        Context temp = mCtx;
        mCtx = null;

        // Write something in the file.
        outputStream.writeObject(command);

        mCtx = temp;

        // Close and flush the stream.
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Exception: ", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Exception: ", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: A poor solution. Making `mCtx` transient would have been better, but making `Position` a static class better still.